# How to update attributes of cells in rappidjs

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I need to update the values of the cell attributes of rappidjs using jquery. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere need to do work like it

```
makeIconInElements(app.graph.toJSON());

function makeIconInElements(json2) {

    if (json2 != undefined) {
       let changedJson = json2;

        changedJson.cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            if (cell.type == ){ }

     

        });
        app.graph.fromJSON(changedJson);
        //resizeCell(app.paper.model);

        //Resizing the cell if icons are outside the box.
        changedJson.cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            let getAllCells = app.graph.getCells();
            if (cell.showIcons) {
                let currentResizingStep = getAllCells.filter(function (el) { return el.attributes.id == cell.id; });
                autoResize(app, currentResizingStep[0]);
            }
        });

        if (lastModifiedStep.attrs.task.status != abs") {
            currentRunningPosition = lastModifiedStep.position;
            app.paperScroller.scroll(currentRunningPosition.x, currentRunningPosition.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: you should use var getcell= app.graph.getCells(pass any id of cell); after this getcell.attributes.set('attrs/height',150);  or getcell.attributes.attrs.width=150;